# dot-notation vs. bracket notation

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have this JavaScript function:

```
function test() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
      var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      document.title = obj.page_title;
    }
  }
  xhr.open("GET", "title.php", true); xhr.send();
}
```

My question is what the difference between:
`obj.page_title` and `obj["page_title"]`
they all work fine to me and return the same value.

Comment: They simply different notations that do the same thing.

Comment: `obj.page_title` is identical to `obj["page_title"]`. The latter is useful when the property name is in a variable or not a valid identifier.

Comment: Just a friendly tip: This question has nothing to do with JSON.parse, even if that is how you create your object. I would consider changing the title. If you change your title though, you will find that this question has been asked a lot of times here before. You will most likely get a lot of downvotest because of this. It is nothing personal, there is just not anything to benefit the community as a whole in this post, so you should probably delete the question, and be happy that you've got a good answer out of it anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are the same:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

The brackets option is useful if you want to use a variable:

```
var key = 'page_title';
obj[key];
```

or if your attribute names have unusual characters like spaces in them:

```
var obj = {
    'title of page': 'title'
}

obj.'title of page' // wrong
obj['title of page'] // right
```

Comment: Im not sure how you have the EXACT same answer as me (but I posted first) and you got two ups and i got a down...

Comment: They're not the same, you didn't mention variables (and I originally didn't mention special characters).

Answer (score -1):

The **only** difference is if you are using a key with a space in it, or the key is stored in a variable.

This will not work

```
obj.i have a space = "foobar";
```

But this will

```
obg['i have a space'] = "foobar";
```

If your key is stored in a variable this bracket notation is better than the dot notation.

```js
var o = {
  foo: bar,
  hello: world
}


for(var key in o){
  console.log(o[key]);  
}
```

Comment: That's not the _only_ difference. The other answer shows another use case.

Comment: There are many more characters than just the space that are invalid in JavaScript identifiers, and thus can't be used with dot notation.